# Logo and Nav Alignment From The Bottom of the Logo

Tags: html, css, position, alignment

I'm making a website that has the logo and a 'home' button on the left side, and 'products' 'about us' 'contact us' on the right side, the home aligns to the bottom of the logo instead of the top of the nav. When I write "nav a{ position: absolute;" it affects all of the nav attributes, but it fixes the home and logo alignment problem. But, if I make a div for the home button so it only targets that attribute, it doesn't work.

Here is my code in the way that fixes the problem but creates another:

```css
nav a {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
align-items: center;
overflow: hidden;
padding-left: 20px;
/* =========================== this is where it fixes 
the problem but creates another one =======*/
position: absolute;  
}

nav {
background-color: #ffffff;
height: 75px;
}

nav li {
list-style: none;
position: relative;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 2%;
align-items: center;
overflow: hidden;
float: right;
display: inline;
}

nav img {  
margin-top: .8%;
margin-left: 2%;
height: 50px;
width: auto;
position: relative;
}

<nav>                      
<img src="bowtie.png" href="index.html"> 
<span><a href="index.html" class="homenav">Home</a></span>             
<li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="photos.html">Products</a></li>                  
</nav>
```

[Fixes problem but creates another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhnR1.png)

[Problem Not Fixed (home aligns with bottom of logo)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3H2fC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things wrong with this. For starters you need to li's need to be used within a ul. Also, float: right; removes elements from the document flow which is causing some of your alignment problems. Lastly display:inline on your "nav li" is collapsing the elements and hiding the text. I've pasted my modified version below. I used position:absolute to absolutely position the menus to the upper right(right:0, top:0) and upper left sides(top:0, left:0).

Lastly, in order to fix the alignment of home I added a height to the ul and li's.

```
<style> 
nav a {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
overflow: hidden;
padding-left: 20px;
}

nav {
background-color: #ffffff;
height: 75px;
}

ul{
    margin-top:0;
    height:50px;
}

.right-menu {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    width:400px;
}

.left-menu {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:300px;
}

nav li {
list-style: none;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 2%;
align-items: center;
overflow: hidden;
display: inline-block;
height:100%;
}

nav img {  
margin-top: .8%;
margin-left: 2%;
height: 50px;
width: auto;
position: relative;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<nav> 
<ul  class="left-menu">
<li><img src="Lorem_Ipsum-logo-1662AFAE6D-seeklogo.com.gif" href="index.html"> </li>
<li><a href="index.html" class="homenav">Home</a></li>             
</ul>
<ul class="right-menu">
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="photos.html">Products</a></li>                  
</ul>   
</nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Hmm... Actually, the 'home' attribute still aligns to the bottom of the logo.